# Cannot see new files added to my git working directory

Tags: git

git version 1.7.4.1

I am using git on Ubuntu.

I have copied some files from another directory to my git working directory. Normally would appear under `Untracked files`. However, they do not appear. So I cannot add them.

When I do a `git status` the new files are not shown.

I tried to add them by doing `git add source.c` then tried `git status`. The file was not show.

So I opened the file and did a `save as` as the same name. git status still failed to see the file.

I have done a `git ls-files` and the new files are shown ok.

I have checked the file permissions and they are the same as all the current files in my git directory.

I have never had this problem before.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: what are the contents of your git ignore? and what files are not showing?

Comment: Do you have any ignore file in repo?

Comment: You should check your git ignore, and perhaps upgrade to the latest version (1.7.6)

Comment: There is nothing in the .gitignore. The files are *.c source files. And I have many of them that I am working on that show ok.

Comment: Can you post the full tree of your repo: `cd your_repo && tree -a` ? (if you don't have tree installed: `sudo apt-get install tree`)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If `git ls-files` shows `source.c`, then it must already be in the index.  This means that it is already tracked, and possibly already committed.  If `source.c` isn't showing up in `git status` at all, then the file must have been committed.

Try modifying the file to see if it shows up as modified in `git status`.  To really convince yourself that the file is checked in, run `git cat-file -p HEAD:source.c` to see the contents of the checked-in file (see `git help revisions` for documentation about the `HEAD:source.c` syntax).

In addition, one or more of the following may be true:

- The file has been modified, but the 'assume unchanged' bit is set in the index.  Take a look at the output of `git ls-files -v source.c`.  If the first column is a lower-case letter, then the 'assume unchanged' bit is set.  This will prevent any changes from showing up in `git status`.  You can turn off the 'assume unchanged' bit by running `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged source.c`.
- The file has been modified, but the 'skip-worktree' bit is set in the index.  If the first column of the output of `git ls-files -v source.c` is `s` or `S` then the 'skip-worktree' bit is set.  You can turn off the 'skip-worktree' bit by running `git update-index --no-skip-worktree source.c`.
- Your index is corrupt.  Try deleting `.git/index` (Git will recreate it as necessary).
- Filesystem issues are preventing `stat()` from working properly.  Try running `git update-index --really-refresh`.  If your working directory is on a network drive (NFS, sshfs, etc.) try moving your repository to a local drive.

Comment: I have the same issue. The first two points didn't apply to me because the first column displayed `H`. I deleted `.git/index`; `git status` now shows tracked files, but they all show up as deleted even though all the files exist. I tried `git update-index --really-refresh` to no avail.

Comment: I used `git reset`, and now `git status` goes back to not displaying my tracked files -- the original problem.

Comment: @Fractal: If `git status` doesn't show the files, but `git ls-files -v` shows `H`, then the file has been committed and has not been modified since it has been committed.  This is normal -- `git status` only shows deviations from normal (untracked files, files that have been modified since staged/committed, files that have been staged but not yet committed).

Comment: @RichardHansen i have similar problem, it shows H and if i modify the file now after committing changes, it doesn't show up in status.
Any idea why?

Comment: @blganesh101: You may want to file a new question because there are a lot of details I'd need, e.g.:  What is the output of `git status` before you modify the file?  What is the output of `git ls-files -v <filename>` after you modify the file?  What version of Git are you using?  What operating system?  What filesystem?  Does deleting `.git/index` change anything?  Does `git update-index --really-refresh <filename>` change anything?

Comment: really the people vote for "Try deleting .git/index"
that is crazy.  the most logical action is try to check the ignore rules, check other responses in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34996761/2062838

Comment: On Windows, I had renamed a file with the same name but different case (don't do this). The file was listed by `git ls-files` but somehow not in the repository. Explicitly deleting and re-adding it in separate commits fixed it. This is almost certainly related to your last point about `stat()`.

Answer (score 59):

It's hard to tell what's wrong from the information given, however as a workaround you can try `git add -f filename.c`. This will add the file even if it would otherwise be ignored.

Comment: This is the correct solution; I've no idea why it is not accepted.

Comment: Agreed. The one above this was probably trying to get to the bottom, but this is just quick and dirty and works

Comment: Worth trying without `-f` (or `--force`, forcing an add) because that suppresses some info that can be helpful (i.e., path is ignored via one of the `.gitignore` files).

Answer (score 26):

This is really a poke in the dark, but I've occasionally had similar issues and it has been a case of one of these:

- You have a rule in .gitignore which ignores the files
- You have a .git dir in one of the directories you've copied

Comment: There is nothing in the .gitignore. The files are *.c source files. And I have many of them that I am working on that show ok. I just copied the files and nothing else. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `.git/info/exclude` and the file referred to by the `core.excludesfile` config variable can also contain ignore rules.  However, I believe that Git prints a friendly "your file wasn't added because it was ignored" message when running `git add` if it's an ignore problem, which means it's probably not an ignore problem.

Comment: +1 the `.gitignore` rule tripped me up. I copied a file into a the build directory, so it worked correctly when built, but didn't appear anywhere in the status.

Comment: Thanks this was useful!

Comment: It turned out to the `.gitignore` for me too. So, do you have to update `.gitignore` of the branch it isn't ignored in? That's how I solved it for now.

Comment: I had a .gitignore file in the directory that was not showing. Removing this solved the issue

Answer (score 18):

I was create a package ending with image.gen which had a corresponding directory ending with image/gen. And there was a .gitignore entry, that was specific to Android gen/.

This was leading to file not getting added to git/ showing in git status.

Check below, it helped me solve the issue.

---

Use `git check-ignore` command to debug your gitignore file (exclude files).

In example:

```
$ git check-ignore -v config.php
.gitignore:2:src    config.php
```

The above output details about the matching pattern (if any) for each given pathname (including line).

So maybe your file extension is not ignored, but the whole directory.

The returned format is:

```
<source> <COLON> <linenum> <COLON> <pattern> <HT> <pathname>
```

Or use the following command to print your `.gitignore` in user and repo folder:

```
cat ~/.gitignore $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitignore $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/info/exclude
```

Alternatively use `git add -f` which allows adding otherwise ignored files.

See: `man gitignore`, `man git-check-ignore` for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28918909/4082503

Answer (score 13):

It is most likely ignored by your `.gitignore` file.

Call `git status --ignored` and see if your file appears.

Answer (score 5):

It could be that 3rd party application updated your "`gitignore_global.txt`" file (`~/.gitignore_global` on Linux / OS X).
It happned to me. I installed "Source tree" and notice after that git does not tracked new files.
It found that "Source tree" changed "gitignore_global.txt" file and add it several extension to not monitor.
Try to locate this file and see if there file's extensions that shuold not be there

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Git did not show any new files added to my project.

Mine was caused by the following:
Somehow my project’s main folder got added to the “Repository-specific ignore list” (that’s what it’s called in SourceTree).
This is the “.gitignore” file in the root of my project’s main folder.

It worked after I deleted the folder name in the “.gitignore” file.

Answer (score 3):

**Android Repo** - 
Same problem i faced- Corrected as below

Somehow i added `"/app" in .gitignore file`. Now after deleting `"/app"` it worked.

Please check your .gitignore.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the .git/index file did the trick. Quite a frustrating error which I seem to come into contact when I clone skeleton modules into my zf2 project.

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global status.showuntrackedfiles all` - Resolution for an old case. You can use `git status untracked-files=all` in the terminal, but it is longer if set `--global`, the code above, it will only need,`git status` for  files appear in the untracked location.

Answer (score 1):

### Try to remove the index.lock file (if there is one)

I had exactly the same issue in my Intellij when trying to add some `Unversioned Files` in my commit window using the `Add to VCS` from the context menu (right click). This action didn't do anything and no errors thrown either.

When I tried to add the file using the command line as follows:

```
git add source.c
```

I got a fatal:

```
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/path/to/repository/.git/index.lock': File exists.
```

Removing the lock file ([as also mentioned in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860765/1697459)) resolved the issue and I was able to add files again like normally.

Apparently the empty lock file was like a leftover from some previous failed action and it was locking the index state preventing adding any new files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Drove me nuts. Finally found out that I had a .gitignore file in my user directory  (C:/Users/user/.gitignore), which was taken into account additionally to the project .gitignore.
After deleting that file in my user directory, everything worked as expected.