# Git - fatal: Unable to create '/path/my_project/.git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: git

I am still getting this error message, when I try to move my project tree on to git repo.

I checked the permissions of my directory with this project and these are set on 777. In terminal in the directory with `my_project` I set:

`git init`

and then if I try

`git add .`

or

`git commit -m "first upload"`

so I'll get the error

```
fatal: Unable to create '/path/my_proj/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a git process crashed in this repository earlier. 
Make sure no other git process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

I tried also create a new repo and there to commit it, but unfortunately still the same error message.

What is the cause of problem?

Comment: I had this issue because I logged in with su in a different terminal, switching back to the first everything went fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367258/using-git-without-sudo-in-many-accounts/33633953#33633953

Comment: bro i had the same problem , use "sudo git add . or git commit -m "first upload" " instead of " git add . or git commit -m "first upload" "

Comment: I got it fixed by changing permissions on .git file per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127255/remove-git-index-lock-permission-denied , refer to answer from Mahshid Zeinaly

Comment: Similar-ish... if you can't create the index.lock, that means you have a full disk.  If running thru WSL, empty some space on your windows harddrive and then run `wsl --shutdown` and try again.

Answer (score 2184, accepted):

Try

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

In your repository directory. The error message is rather explicit as to what causes it typically, so if you have no other git processes running (which is the normal case), go ahead and delete that file.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. Now I run `git commit -a` and then I checked out `git status`, there was a message `# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`. But I still don't see an imported files in my repo on bitbucket. In how time will be transfered the files from my local directory to web repo?

Comment: It doesn't happen automatically. You need to execute the command `git push` to push your changes to the web server. Details on how this works are here: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem but I can't solve it this way because the .git/index.lock file doesn't appear to exist: `touch .get/index.lock` returns `touch: .get/index.lock: No such file or directory`

Comment: On closer inspection, I see a slight difference in the error message. Mine says `:Permission denied`

Comment: Emerson, you seem to be looking for .get instead of .git which would not exist.

Comment: I had trouble with this, I used a similar command, with the '-f'      from my home directory, I entered: "rm .git/index.lock"

Comment: i am running this command but still getting the same error /.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Any clue? what else possibly needs to be done ?

Comment: maybe i have a different git release, needed this:
`rm -Force ./.git/index.lock`

Comment: Permission denied means you need to give the user you are using Git with read/write permissions on the file. Check out chmod command (on *nix or Properties -> Security tab on WIndows)

Comment: just fyi, in windows I did this:

Comment: If your error says "Permission Denied", you have probably copied the files from somewhere else, and don't have permissions over the .git directory. Use `ls -l` to see permissions, then use `sudo chown -R username ./*`and `sudo chgrp -R username ./*` to change user and group to your own for all files in the project.

Comment: Years after this question was answered... your still saving peoples lives!

Comment: In my case, that file doesn't exist either, the error message comes in the middle of a rebase. So there is no file I could remove and this seems like a "real" error.

Comment: i don't have .lock file under .git directory but still I am getting an error.

Comment: No one actually reads the messages. It goes more like _Oh, it failed. What do I do?_ haha

Comment: @Apie `.get` is the Northern version. To be used solely when drinking [Newkie Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcastle_Brown_Ale).

Comment: In my case, it was because I had a script to do some git-related stuff, and my editor was detecting a change of branch, and trying to reload changed buffers while the rest of my script was running.

Comment: @cslotty This file didn't seem to exist on my system either, but somehow running this command fixed it.

Comment: The error I am seeing is the same "fatal: Unable to create", Would that not be a permission issue in the .git folder? I don't have an index.lock file but still get the error.

Comment: I had BitDefender which was blocking Git to make changes. I simply allowed Git to run from my BitDefener menu.

Comment: Its functional now after: Manually deleting the files from ./git/ directory. so no restrictions in deleting the file from console or view.

Comment: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: For those like me that keep coming back to this issue; You can add this line as a shortcut for your (shell) terminal: `alias rmlockfile='rm -f ./.git/index.lock'`. Add it to your .zshconfig file

Answer (score 198):

In Windows, do this in the command prompt from the repo directory:

```
cd .git
del index.lock
```

UPDATE: 
I have found that I don't need to do this procedure if I wait a moment after I close out the files I'm working on before I try to switch branches.  I think sometimes this issue occurs due to git catching up with a slow file system. Other, more git-knowledgeable developers can chime in if they think this is correct.

Comment: Strangely enough, I get the error about the file but then when I try to delete the file in cmd.exe, it says file not found :) Same result with absolute and relative paths. But in Git Bash, it works (with `rm -f index.lock`)

Comment: In my case, I executed "Fetch" after a couple of restarts of Sourcetree and worked.

Comment: Though it won't be a problem in this case since we are dealing with a single file with 0 size, it is a better practice in general to use rmdir /s.

del in cmd only removes files. Even then, without /s it won't recurse and will only remove files in the top-level directory.

So, for cmd, you should be using rmdir /s to recursively delete all files and folders.

Comment: actually i have a react project, which needs to be uploaded everytime in the github, I always add it remotely, and i do it by "git init" but  the problem is , there is already a .git file.., even though I delete that, this error still exists.

Answer (score 38):

Try quitting Xcode - since it's a git client, you have to quit Xcode to avoid problems with git on the command line.

Comment: Nice!  Note that Xcode AND other Git clients can be culprits.  In my case it took closing gitX also.

Comment: After having to delete my lock file 10 times or so this morning I finally stumbled upon this answer.  Don't know how xcode opened up but it was sure trashing my workflow.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 36):

I was having the same problem. I tried

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

and the console gave me an error message. Then, I tried

```
rm --force ./.git/index.lock
```

and that worked.

Good Luck!
This works super

Comment: I dont see .git folder in my case. I only see ./ and ../ as far as hidden directory are concerns.

Comment: What type of computer are you on?

Answer (score 36):

In my .git directory, there was no index.lock file.  So, using the Git Bash shell, I ran...

```
cd .git
touch index.lock
rm index.lock
```

The touch command created the file, and the problem went away.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  I received the similar error message as OP.  This fixed me, and maybe could help others.

Comment: I experienced a slight variant of this: (1) I experienced the error message and experimented with different 'fixes'; (2) I found that `index.lock` did not exist; (3) I used the above `touch` command; (4) my git client stopped functioning normally (at best, it slowed to a crawl); (5) I deleted `index.lock`; (6) the repository began functioning normally again.

Comment: Definitely shouldnt be downvoted, sorted my problem out.  I didnt have an index.lock file, but once I created one, and subsequently removed it, the commit worked.

Comment: `touch index.lock` implies John was on *NIX, but I just did the equivalent on Windows 10 (create an `index.lock` file with a text editor, delete it immediately, and profit), and the problem's gone.

Comment: It's downvoted because it's missing the last step of deleting the `index.lock` file that you just created with `touch`.

Comment: I keep getting `No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?`

Comment: Though it's a bit weird, why you have to create it and then delete it? But this is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: My Windows 10 with Git Bash working well

Comment: yep, this is what worked for me also. issue on mac os and vs code

Comment: This is kind of absurd but it worked.

Comment: I don't understand it, but it worked

Answer (score 26):

You need to delete the index.lock file.

In Linux

```
cd .git
rm -f index.lock
```

In Windows(10), do this in the command prompt from the repo directory:

```
cd .git
del index.lock
```

Answer (score 16):

> Did you accidentally create the repository using the `root` user?

It just happens that I created the git repository as the `root` user.

I deleted the git repository and created it again without `sudo` and it works.

Comment: Yeap, that's it. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

i have this problem too, and i find it really a permission problem. so i do this:

```
sudo chown -R : .git #change group
sudo chmod -R 775 .git #change permission
```

then ererything is great, and gaa is success.

and then i use gp, i get another error almost the same error

```
sudo chown -R "${USER:-$(id -un)}" . #use this can fix the problem
```

Comment: brilliant, what does this do? "${USER:-$(id -un)}"

Comment: Did not work on Windows 10 + git bash (even w/o the sudo)

Answer (score 9):

In Windows, I only managed to be able to delete the lock file after Ending Task for all Git Windows (32bit) processes in the Task Manager.

**Solution** (Win 10)

**1. End Task** for all Git Windows (32bit) processes in the Task Manager

**2. Delete** the .git/index.lock file

Answer (score 9):

1. Run Task Manager, Locate Git for windows process and kill it.
2. Delete index.lock file under .git folder
3. It worked for me !

Answer (score 7):

In Mac OS X do this in the command prompt from the repo directory:

```
cd .git
rm index.lock
```

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 7):

The solution that worked for me was closing sublime text because the running git process was initiated by the editor.

Comment: I've recently installed the Sublime Text plugin GitSavvy and had this error only since then. Thanks for the hint, @snorkelzebra

Answer (score 6):

If after you try:

> rm -f ./.git/index.lock

you get:

> rm: cannot unlink 'index.lock': Permission denied

Try closing all software that might be using Git. 
I had Source Tree and Visual Studio opened and after closing both the command worked.

Answer (score 6):

I think there's a better solution than removing the file (and god knows what will happen next when removing/creating a file with sudo):

```
git gc
```

Comment: Because it's windows? Try to use cmder or maybe use git kraken which maybe fix some stuff

Comment: in the middle of all these response all saying the same thing again and again (and `./.git/index.lock` no existing), this solved my issue :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using one of `#intelliJ` IDEs and receiving this msg (i'm using `#webtorm`), please notice that this problem can occur because of hiding one of project folders (inside settings), and this can prevent `GIT`from merging.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the solution was to wait 5 minutes. Obviously my previous operation was still running but I just didn't know it. I was using tortoise git on windows.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a submodule, try this instead on your repository directory :

```
rm -f ../.git/modules/submodule-name/index.lock
```

change submodules-name to your submodule name.

Answer (score 4):

Use This:

```
rm -Force ./.git/index.lock
```

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT USE the **Atom** `platformio-atom-ide-terminal` Plugin to do this. 
USE THE TERMINAL OF YOUR DISTRO DIRECTLY.

I kept getting this error while rebasing/squishing commits and didn't know why because I had done it before several times.

Didn't matter how many times I would delete the `index.lock` file, every time it would fail.

Turns out it was because I was using the **ATOM EDITOR** terminal plugin. Once I used the terminal that ships with Ubuntu it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You have problem with `.git/index.lock` so delete it using below command.

**Command:**

> sudo rm -rf .git/index.lock

Answer (score 3):

I tried it with many methods several times but this one worked for me (I used PyCharm's terminal)  :

```
$ cd .git/

$ rm -f index.lock
```

Then I tried again to create an empty git repo :

```
$ git init

$ git add .

$ git commit -m "commit msg"
```

Answer (score 2):

The resolution for this problem is copying the three xcode/project files in the directory and then creating new directory (Whereever else) and then paste the three files/directories.

Answer (score 2):

**Also we can just kill git process.** I receive the same issue via GUI app for git, something goes wrong and git makes some work infinitely. Killing process will freeze application that works with git, just restart it and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

In case, for whatever reason, you are doing a rebase from a folder that's being sync'd by a cloud service (dropbox, drive, onedrive, etc), you should pause or turn off syncing as it will interfere with permissions during the rebase.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was

```
rm -r .git-credentials.lock
```

Answer (score 2):

I had changed my directory permission so I knew it could be permission related. In my case I removed unwanted (_www) users and then applied read/write permission to everyone by apply changed to all contents. This is on Mac

[image: Directory Permission on Mac]

Answer (score 2):

All the remove commands didn't work for me what I did was to navigate there using the path provided in git and then deleting it manually.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is using git svn, I had the same problem but could not remove the file since it was not there!. After checking permissions, touching the file and deleting it, and I don't remember what else, this did the trick:

- checkout the master branch.
- git svn rebase (on master)
- checkout the branch you were working on
- git svn rebase

Answer (score 2):

A little adding because I had to use different answers to get the actual solution (for me).

**This did it for me:**

1. Open branch you are working on
2. Open terminal (I use terminal in Git GUI)
3. Typ in command: `cd .git`
4. Typ in command: `rm -f index.lock`

Some may have to use `-Force` instead of `-f`.  You can check the command lines of your terminal by executing a command in your terminal something like: `git help`.

Answer (score 2):

simply go to D:/project/androidgc/.git/ this directory and delete index.lock this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions are right:

```
Just remove .git from your corrupted repository, 

then copy this file if back from another clone (if you don't have it in another machine, just clone it).
```

Finally, what made the difference to me:

- Avoid using ***sudo*** to unzip or copy the new .git folder. Git won't have access to the .git folder if you use superuser rights to create it

Answer (score 0):

I had this occur when I was in a subdirectory of the directory corresponding to the root folder of the repo (ie the directory in which .git was). Moving up to the root directory solved the problem - at the cost of making all file references a bit more inconvenient as you have to go path/to/folder/foo.ext instead of just foo.ext

Answer (score 0):

A restart of the machine worked for me. None of the solutions provided so far worked for me.

Env
Windows 10 + Git Bash

EDIT: I see the same solution was here: [git index.lock File exists when I try to commit, but cannot delete the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282632/3487604)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing the lock file won't make it work.
Restarting the computer works for me

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this on Windows, my issue was the same but I needed to delete the `HEAD.lock` file as I didn't have an `index.lock`.