# How do I fix a failed git commit?

Tags: git

I am new to `git` and was trying to commit, but I got stuck in what looked like `vi` which I'm not familiar with. I managed to get out of it, but I think I got out the wrong way because my git status says "changes not staged," but I still can't try again. Could someone tell me what I can do to fix the still hanging process and commit my changes?

here is the error

```
fatal: Unable to create '/.git/index.lock': File exists.
If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

not i took out the full path

As always thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full results of `git status`.

Comment: Note that you can change the editor used for commit messages via `git config --global core.editor EDITOR_NAME`, where `EDITOR_NAME` is an executable in your path (or the full path).

Comment: You might want to see this question on how to change the default editor in git: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows

Comment: rm -f ./.git/index.lock
This worked for me, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists

Comment: @RAJCHOW that worked for me too. I'd "stopped" another git add -a process with CTR+Z

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're not doing anything with git at the moment (i.e., not doing a push or pull or running a git script in the repository, for any reason), you could just remove the lock file manually and try again.

Also, git expects a "commit message" describing your changes. Assuming you don't want an editor to open, you can provide an inline message using the `-m` option:

```
git commit -am "Changed this, that, and the other thing"
```

Comment: ok and assuming that works how to i save and changes when it brings up vi

Comment: @mcgrailm: I edited my answer, check it out and let me know if that helps.

Comment: had to add each file first rather than using git commit -a "changed this ,that and the other thing" kept get message saying changes not staged

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that you need to use `git add` on your files first, or else use the `-a` flag to pull in everything that has changes.

Answer (score 14):

Removing **index.lock** file manually from .git directory worked.

or

From command line:

```
$ rm -rf .git/index.lock
```

**Note:** Make sure that only one *index* file exist on .git directory

Answer (score 1):

Note the message will improve and be more explicit with git 2.9 (June 2016), in order to invite you to consider all the causes *before* removing that lock yourself.

See [commit aed7480](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aed7480ca4c284089a3b332fae770b4056eb08fc), [commit 3030c29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3030c295baee355d0b454a2d54f295153f8ea6a8) (01 Mar 2016) by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy).
Helped-by: [Moritz Neeb (`zormit`)](https://github.com/zormit).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3b8c4b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b8c4b727f389e3470ec31b20e2a97496da36086), 03 Apr 2016)</sup>

> ### lockfile: improve error message when lockfile exists
>
> A common mistake leading a user to see this message is to launch "`git commit`", let the editor open (and forget about it), and try again to
>   commit.
>
> The previous message was going too quickly to "a git process crashed"
>   and to the advice "remove the file manually".
>
> This patch modifies the message in two ways:
>
> - first, it considers that "another process is running" is the norm, not the exception,
> - and it explicitly hints the user to look at text editors.
>
> The message is 2 lines longer, but this is not a problem since experienced users do not see the message often.

Answer (score 1):

mine was solved with both answers from **Platinum Azure** then **Suhail Taj**

```
git commit -am "Changed this, that, and the other thing"
```

Then

```
$ rm -rf .git/index.lock
```