# Git index.lock File exists when I try to commit, but I cannot delete the file

Tags: git

When I do 'git commit', I'm getting the following:

`fatal: Unable to create 'project_path/.git/index.lock': File exists.`

However, when I do `ls project_path/.git/index.lock` it's saying the file doesn't exist. What should I do? I've also noticed that project_path/.git is owned by *root* and am not sure if that has anything to do with the problem I'm encountering.

The Git version is 1.7.5.4

---

It seems that the problem most likely was another process I had running, that was writing (unbeknownst to me) to the project directory. I restarted my machine and then I had no problem committing.

Comment: It could very well be a permissions problem where Git assumes that since it can't create the file it already exists. Have you tried taking ownership of the directory or executing your command using sudo?

Comment: I got same error then I tried squash and reword in one rebase operation. I just del reword and all works fine, and reword on next rebase.

Comment: I think your explanation on another app accessing the git repo is correct. Had the same problem during a rebase. Gitx was running. Once I quit it git worked fine.

Comment: It works for me   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916339/error-in-deleting-addind-file-from-appharbor-using-git-unable-to-create-f-git

Comment: @asahi: Do you maybe want to accept an answer? This will help future readers.

Comment: @MERose: I would, but this was 3 years ago on a different machine from the one I have now, and as can be seen by my updated post, I had figured out a solution. Not sure what can be done to help future readers, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - fatal: Unable to create '/path/my\_project/.git/index.lock': File exists.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Comment: @asahi: You can post the content of your edit (which was the solution) as an answer and then accept that. (Although the more general solution than 'restart the machine' is that another process was accessing the directory; restarting just cuts through the Gordian knot of trying to figure out which one and why. : ) In my case, it was my IDE.) Anyway, people frequently answer their own questions when they find their own solutions, which you did.

Comment: Make sure to use git 2.8.4+ (June 2016). [See my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37710754/6309)

Comment: It seemed that killing my BabelJS compiler/watcher in the repo fixed the issue for me. I got the clue from @TheWho

Comment: For me I uninstall Git Desktop then open Git Bash locally and add, committ and it worked. Previously it did not work because I tried to install the clone folder in OneDrive directory.

Answer (score 457):

On Linux, Unix, [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), or [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), try:

`rm -f .git/index.lock`

On Windows Command Prompt, try:

`del .git\index.lock`

Comment: I see that sometimes the lock file gets deleted automatically. Any clue why this file need to be deleted manually sometimes ?

Comment: I don't have an index.lock, what do? :(

Comment: Given that the problem in the question was that he was not able to delete the file, why do you think trying to delete the file should be the solution?

Comment: For me closing and opening SourceTree resolved the issue... Temporarily I suppose.

Comment: Closing PHPStorm was also required this time. Maybe something in there is locking it.

Comment: On Windows close all applications that use git then open the Task Manager and kill all git processes. Then delete the index.lock file.

Comment: @skyking in the original question there's an error that says `fatal: Unable to create 'project_path/.git/index.lock': File exists.`, it says "File exists", and deleting it would simple solution.

Why would I suggest deleting a file if it's not even in the original question?

Comment: Windows: cd .git
touch index.lock
rm index.lock

Answer (score 52):

For Windows:

- From a PowerShell console opened as administrator, try

  ```
  rm -Force ./.git/index.lock
  ```
- If that does not work, you must kill all *git.exe* processes

  ```
  taskkill /F /IM git.exe
  ```

  > SUCCESS: The process "git.exe" with PID 20448 has been terminated. 
  > SUCCESS: The process "git.exe" with PID 11312 has been terminated. 
  > SUCCESS: The process "git.exe" with PID 23868 has been terminated. 
  > SUCCESS: The process "git.exe" with PID 27496 has been terminated. 
  > SUCCESS: The process "git.exe" with PID 33480 has been terminated. 
  > SUCCESS: The process "git.exe" with PID 28036 has been terminated. \

  ```
  rm -Force ./.git/index.lock
  ```

Comment: Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'f' is ambiguous.

Comment: thanks, @MikePalmice, I updated to -Force. Seems they changed the API

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect for me the taskkill then i did the force which worked :) thanks man. @AndreiEpure

Answer (score 21):

On a Windows platform running [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015) RC (v4.6.00057) in combination with [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) (v1.6.14.0), it will give this error as well.

Solution:
Assuming you want to use Sourcetree as source code manager, simply disable the source control provider inside Visual Studio like this:

1. Go to: menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Source Control*
2. Select Current source control plug-in as: None

Comment: Even though my VS is not supposed to even access those repositories, this was the problem anyway when rebasing with SourceTree.

Comment: Thank you, problem is still there with Update 3.

Comment: Closing Visual Studio also works (deleted the index.lock file.)

Answer (score 14):

1. check if the Git process still running (`ps -ef  | grep git`)
2. if not, remove the locked file
3. if yes, kill the Git process at first.

Comment: This presumes are particular platform. Liunx? Where was it tested? What distribution and version?

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

if you have no other Git process running, and then just delete the *index.lock* file of the respective project.

Comment: Worked on my mac's environment.

Comment: What context? [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)? (it [isn't Windows/PowerShell](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html) as [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) (the alias for `rm`) doesn't have option '`-f`').

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes correct in the context of Linux

Answer (score 8):

This is happening when you cancel pulling from *origin* in the middle.

So you can manually delete the *index.lock* file from your *.git* directory:

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

[cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) into your project directory and run this command.

Comment: Given that the problem in the question was that he was not able to delete the file, why do you think trying to delete the file should be the solution?

Comment: +1 @skyking. Deleting a file is obvious, the problem is there is no file to delete and the problem persists.

Answer (score 8):

1. Close every window that is potentially affecting this *.git/index.lock* file
2. Delete the *.git/index.lock* file.
3. Open your command line editor and [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to the location of your Git files.

(If the file is created, simply from *cd* into that location, then the problem is your editor. Close your editor. Do not use this editor again for this task. Open a different kind of editor - Windows PowerShell or simply [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe). Now you can use Git commands to continue.)

Answer (score 7):

I just had this issue... [Gitbox](https://osxdaily.com/2010/08/23/git-gui-for-mac-gitbox/) was at fault. So maybe you had a GUI running that was causing problems.

Comment: It wasn't a GUI but I had a separate process that was writing to the project directory. I couldn't figure it out and it was driving me nuts.

Comment: It looks like GitX likes to cause this problem too.

Comment: 6 years later, it was Atom for me

Answer (score 6):

`del .git\index.lock` worked for me.

I was facing this issue while checking out a new branch from the *master* branch.

Check out easily happened after deleting the `index.lock` file.

Comment: On Windows, presumably? What context? [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)?

Answer (score 6):

In my case simply, go to `project_path/.git` and delete the *index.lock* file. Try to push your code it will work.

Comment: Orphaned index.lock file. Generally, if you have an index.lock file, it's because a Git process is running or waiting on a prompt for user input. However, if the editing process is terminated or becomes unresponsive, the index.lock file can be left behind and remain present even if no Git process is running. This orphaned index.lock file will prevent other Git processes from editing the repository.

Comment: Removing an Orphaned index.lock file. Note on Windows it's just "index" with no lock extension. 
If you suspect that you have an orphaned index.lock file, first verify that you don't have any Git processes running. To check for long-running Git operations, open Task Manager, sort by name, and look for git.exe or other Git-related processes. If you see any, you can wait a few moments for them to complete and try the Git operation again. If you don't have any Git processes running, you can delete the index.lock file and try the Git operation again.

Comment: The above comments are courtesy of the Git documentation on learn.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 5):

Probably (it has happened to me), the *ls* command is saying *it doesn't exist*, because the current user doesn't have permissions to reach that directory or file.

Remove the lock and **make sure you are executing Git with the right user** in order to avoid permission problems.

If you are in a GNU/Linux box with *sudo* command:

```
sudo rm project_path/.git/index.lock
```

Comment: In Windows, you can check to see if the folder is read-only with right-click->Properties->Attributes.

Comment: Given that the problem in the question was that the file was non-existing, why do you think trying to delete the file should be the solution?

Comment: @skyking Permission problems show the same error. Indeed, I came to this question because the title. I wrote my answer as one possible solution and some votes confirm that it occurs to other people too ;)

Comment: @caligari Not exactly. Permission problem gives another answer to `ls project_path/.git/index.lock`.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes Git creates a lock file associated with your repo while you are making any changes or most probably when you are using sub modules.

The error message will show you the path of the lock file.

Fix: Just manually go to the path in terminal and delete the lock file by

```
rm index.lock
```

It should help.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) when switching branch by double-clicking on it. The problem is not very common and [Atlassian knows about it](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1130), but they decided not to fix it.

Fortunately, there is a solution. Instead of double-clicking on a branch you want to switch, just right click and choose "Checkout [branch name]". It should succeed now.

Comment: thanks, right click > checkout works as an alternative. the error message is quite misleading especially when index.lock does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

I have come across the very same scenario. I even haven't done any changes in my local code. I have just edited a file and reverted it. I have simply deleted the below file in the hidden *.git* folder. It worked!

> project_path/.git/index.lock

Comment: Yes, but directly manipulating files in folder *.git* may be risky.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem today where Sourcetree had spawned several Git processes that kept running even after closing Sourcetree.  Here is how I fixed it.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> or type "Task Manager" in windows start to start [Task Manage](https://Task%20Manage)r.
2. Look for all processes named "git", "git-lfs", etc. as shown in the screenshot below.  Right click and select "End process" to kill each of them.
3. Delete the *.git/index.lock* file.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager, including some Git processes]

Answer (score 3):

Unless you actually intended for root to own your repository, this sounds like you accidentally ran a Git command as root (maybe even the initial clone/init). If you meant to do that, then you'll have to live with running all Git commands in the repository as root. If you didn't, run `sudo chown your-user[:your-group] -R .git` to take ownership of it, and then see if things work.

Comment: In my case I had messed up the mode of files and directories inside `.git` and I corrected them with: `find .git -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` and also `find .git -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` I had messed up the modes when moving my git project from one computer to the other

Comment: In my case I added write permission to .git files `sudo chmod g+w .git -R`

Answer (score 2):

Starting [git 2.8.4 (June 2016)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.8.4.windows.1), this should not happen anymore.

See [issue 755](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/755) which should also alleviate the issue ([commit 2db0641](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/2db0641fa2c7ff0ae2521b7045634cfd6d69d70d)):

> ### Make sure temporary file handles are not inherited by child processes
>
> Prevent child processes from inheriting a handle to `index.lock`.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this question in Windows 10.

when I tried del `./.git/index.lock`, it told me `cannot remove 'index.lock': Device or resource busy`.

I finally got the reason:

The computer has two processes which uses Git:

- [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)
- [Cmder](https://cmder.net/)

I used *cmder.exe* to do `git commit` and errors occurred.

So the solution is use Git Bash or *terminate* Git Bash and then use *cmder.exe*.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple Git clients working on the same local repository compete for that lock.  Each client should wait until the lock is released by the other party to be a good citizen.  For us, [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) or [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) appear to be be doing some maintenance in the background while we were are running large commit scripts.

*Perhaps 'git' itself should support a '--retriesWhenLocked 5' argument to support retries.* or even default to this when run manually.

Here is a [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) wrapper around Git named "gitr" that retries until *index.lock* disappears, using default five tries, three seconds between each.  It never removes the *index.lock*, assuming the user should intervene.  It was extracted from a larger commit script.  It only has minimal testing with simple arguments.

- Copy the script to *C:\bin* and add *C:\bin* to $PATH.
- From PowerShell: `gitr --help`
- From DOS ([cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)): `powershell gitr --help`

**gitr.ps1**

```
    #requires -version 2
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        gitr
    .DESCRIPTION
        Run "git" as an external process with retry and capturing stdout stderr.
    .NOTES
      2017/05/16 crokusek: Initial version
    #>

    #---------------------------------------------------------[Initializations]--------------------------------------------------------

    #Set Error Action
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

    #----------------------------------------------------------[Declarations]----------------------------------------------------------

    $scriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    #Set-Location $scriptDir

    ## Disabled logging
    # Log File
    # $logFile = "$($scriptDir)\getr.log"
    # If (Test-Path $logFile) { Clear-Content $logFile }

    #-----------------------------------------------------------[Functions]------------------------------------------------------------

    Function Log([string]$msg, [bool]$echo = $true)
    {
        $timestamp = "$(get-date -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'):  "
        $fullmsg = $msg -replace '(?ms)^', $timestamp  # the (?ms) enables multiline mode

        ## Disabled Logging
        # Add-content $LogFile -value $fullmsg

        if ($echo)
        {
            Write-Host $msg
        }
    }

    Function ExecSimple([string]$command, [bool]$echo=$true, [bool]$stopOnNonZeroExitCode=$true)
    {
        $command, $args = $command -split " "
        return Exec $command $args $echo $stopOnNonZeroExitCode
    }

    Function Exec([string]$exe, [string[]]$arguments, [bool]$echo=$true, [bool]$stopOnNonZeroExitCode=$true)
    {
        # Passing $args (list) as a single parameter is the most flexible, it supports spaces and double quotes

        $orgErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
        Try
        {
            $error.clear()  # this apparently catches all the stderr pipe lines

            if ($false -and $exe -eq 'git')  # todo make this a generic flag
            {
                $exe = "$($exe) 2>&1"
            }

            $output = ""

            $argflattened = $arguments -join ' '
            Log "`n% $($exe) $($arguments)`n"

            # This way some advantages over Invoke-Expressions or Start-Process for some cases:
            #      - merges stdout/stderr line by line properly,
            #      - echoes the output live as it is streamed to the current window,
            #      - waits for completion
            #      - works when calling both console and windows executables.
            #
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"  # required in order to catch more than 1 stderr line in the exception

            if ($echo)
            {
                # Using "cmd.exe" allows the stderr -> stdout redirection to work properly.  Otherwise the 2>&1 runs after PS for
                # some reason.  When a command such as "git" writes to stderr, powershell was terminating on the first stderr
                # line (and stops capturing additional lines).
                #
                # but unfortuantely cmd has some bizarre de-quoting rules that weren't working for all cases.
                #& cmd /c "`"" $exe $arguments "`"" | Tee-Object -variable output | Write-Host | out-null

                # This is simplest but has some issues with stderr/stdout (stderr caught as exception below)
                #
                & $exe $arguments 2>&1 | tee -variable output | Write-Host | out-null
            }
            else
            {
                & $exe $arguments 2>&1 | tee -variable output | out-null
            }

            $output = $output -join "`r`n"

            if ($stopOnNonZeroExitCode -and !$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
            {
                throw [System.Exception] "Exit code ($($LASTEXITCODE)) was non-zero. Output:`n$($output)"
            }
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException]
        {
            $output = $_.Exception.ToString().Replace("System.Management.Automation.RemoteException:", "").Trim()

            if ($output.Contains("fatal"))
            {
                throw
            }

            if ($echo)
            {
                Log $output
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            $ErrorActionPreference = $orgErrorActionPreference;
        }

        if (-not $output -eq "")
        {
            Log $output $false  # don't echo to screen as the pipe above did
        }

        return $output
    }

    Function ExecWithRetry([string]$exe, [string[]]$arguments, [bool]$echo=$true, [bool]$stopOnNonZeroExitCode=$true,
                          [int]$maxRetries = 5, [int]$msDelay = 3000, [AllowNull()][string]$exceptionMustContain = $null)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxRetries; $i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Exec $exe $arguments $echo $stopOnNonZeroExitCode
                return
            }
            catch
            {
                if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($exceptionMustContain) -and $_.Exception.ToString().Contains($exceptionMustContain))
                {
                    Log "Last Error from $($exe) is retryable ($($i + 1) of $($maxRetries))" $true
                    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds ($msDelay);
                    continue
                }

                throw
            }
        }

        throw [System.Exception] "Unable to successfully exec '$($exe)' within $($maxRetries) attempts."
    }

    Function GitWithRetry([string[]]$arguments, [bool]$echo=$true)
    {
        ExecWithRetry "git" $arguments $echo -exceptionMustContain "Another git process seems to be running"
    }

#-----------------------------------------------------------[Main]------------------------------------------------------------

function Main([string[]]$arguments)
{
    GitWithRetry @($arguments)
}


#-------------------------------------- Startup ------------------------------------
try
{
    Main $args
    Exit 0
}
catch
{
    #Log "*** A fatal error occured: $($_.Exception)"
    #Read-Host -Prompt "`nA fatal error occurred, press enter to close."
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to navigate to the specific folder of your project...
Like if your project name is *Firstproject*, then first go to the directory of the project...

Then type `cd .git`.

Then after navigating to the Git folder, type `del index.lock`.
After the deletion of the file *index.lock*, you will be able to commit and push as before.

Comment: On Windows, presumably?

Comment: thanks. It solved my issue with not being able to discard changes that occured when I tried to merge branches...

Answer (score 2):

Is your code in a directory that Dropbox is syncing?  Try pausing Dropbox.

I kept getting the same condition, but once I paused Dropbox (the interface gives you the option to pause for 30 minutes, 1 hour, ...), it never happened again.

Comment: This solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe because when you try to pull code and stop the process suddenly.

Just simple way to do:

- `rm -f ./.git/index.lock`
- after that, `git status` on the `master/main` branch
- still see a lot of red color files.  Run `git reset --hard origin/master` to remove all local changes and make it similar to `origin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same error, but the issue was not the lock file. Instead the issue was that I had copied the contents of another Git repository into this repository, including the .git invisible folder.

So, [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) was confused about which repository I wanted to stage files to (there being a mismatch between the repository Sourcetree thought I was in, and the one that the contents of my embedded .git directory said I should be in).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with [TortoiseGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit) with [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) on Windows. I wasn't able to delete remove *./.git/index.lock* even with administrative privileges. I tried both Cygwin and a command prompt, but it said the file was in use by another process.

I found that I had two instances of *TortoiseProc.exe* running. I killed one of them, and closed all of my [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer) windows, and then was able to delete the file. I don't know if killing an instance of *TortoiseProc.exe* was the solution or closing Windows Explorer windows.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to delete the .index file and allow Git to rebuild another.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have an inex.lock file to delete, but what worked for me was removing the Read-Only check from the Attributes window of the folder Properties dialog.

Comment: Re *"inex.lock"*: Do you mean *"index.lock"*?

Answer (score 1):

I created an empty *index.lock* file, and deleted it using a Windows command.

Comment: Why did you create an empty *index.lock* file?

Answer (score 1):

In my [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) application I am not able to do a commit or switch to any other commit/branch. That time it shows an error like

> fatal: Unable to create blah blah blah..

I simply resolve this by going to the *.git* folder (in the project explorer directory). And delete the index—[file type: LOCK file]. Now I get back all access in Sourcetree...

Please make sure the index lock file... Suppose you don’t get the file type, change the fileview settings on the computer. Note: the *.git* folder is normally a hidden type of folder.

Comment: Hiding of the file extensions in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

What did it for me was:

`git rebase --abort` and restart the rebase.

As [Andrew mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282632/git-index-lock-file-exists-when-i-try-to-commit-but-cannot-delete-the-file#comment65921846_11466435), I was also using [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm) when this happened. I didn't have to close it, though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there wasn't any *index.lock* file to delete. I was trying to commit 109 files after formatting with [Prettier](https://prettier.io/). Committing less files at the time is what finally "resolved" the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was Windows, not shut down completely.

Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.

Chances are that Windows really is hibernated. Windows does this automatically when you tell it to shutdown normally. The benefit is that you get a faster apparent start-up time.

To shutdown Windows without hibernating, issue the following at a command-prompt (in Windows):

```
shutdown /s
```

You might also want include `/t 0` for immediate shutdown.

I found a nice tutorial to set up a launcher for this: *How to Do a Full Shutdown in Windows 8 Without Disabling Hybrid Boot*.

The simpler approach to actually shutting down Windows is to 'restart' (rather than 'shutdown'), but then intercept the boot process and boot Linux instead of letting it boot Windows.

**Credit**: [nobar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6764/nobar)

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you're using an alternate command line Git client, like [hub](https://github.com/github/hub).

I've been using hub as an aliased replacement for Git for a couple of years, but recently wrote a Bash script that does a bunch of Git work in it, and started to get this index lock issue.

I couldn't find the fix until I remembered I was running hub instead of Git. I removed that and the problem went away!

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the error:

> Using index info to reconstruct a base tree... 
> Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge... 
> fatal: Unable to create '/home/user/project/.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
> git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
> process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

But I couldn't find (nor delete) that .git/index.lock file.

In my case, [Git Cola](https://git-cola.github.io/) was running!

It obviously creates that .git/index.lock every once in a while, or caused by the rebase I was doing on the command line and during which I received that error - so Git Cola obviously "disturbs" the command line run of Git (or some Git CLI operations).

This is solved by closing git-cola during a command line git rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes another Git client may interfere when there are multiple installed.

I.e., make sure with the [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) or [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process) that `TGitCache` from [TortoiseGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit) is not active in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. If you will check the whole error message, it also says that there are some process that are using the Git process that blocks you from deleting *index.lock*.

You may have an IDE open, like [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio), or related software that Git is integrated into. Close it and try re-stashing your file.

Answer (score 0):

In [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)):

1. develop all processes
2. Kill all Git processes
3. Delete the locked file

Comment: Was it on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

- The problem was solved for me by deleting the repository you are trying to commit the changes and clone the latest version from the remote (if using a remote Git server).
- If it's local copy the data from directory and initialize a new Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the culprit was Windows security. It was blocking `git.exe` from running. You can check the notifications tab on the bottom right of your screen.

The message will show like this:

```
Virus and threat protection
unauthorized changes blocked
controlled folder access blocked git.exe from running
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio (such as Visual Studio 2019) you can see this error occur when trying to commit changes with Git.

It can happen when you don't have a connection with Team Server. To correct it,

1. Inside Visual Studio, from the Team menu, select the command Manage Connections.
2. Look in the Solution Explorer -- you should see Team Explorer - Connect.
3. Connect to the project you are working on by clicking it in the tree listed. (This step works if you have previously worked on the project.)
4. Once connected, try your commit again.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

1. removed the project.git\index file manually
2. in the terminal: `git reset`
3. synup project

Comment: What is *"synup"*? Sync up?

Comment: What context? Windows? [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)? What kind of project?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I randomly get a

```
fatal: Не удалось создать «/home/mingun/project/.git/index.lock»: Файл существует.

Похоже, что другой процесс git запущен в этом репозитории,
например редактор открыт из «git commit». Пожалуйста, убедитесь,
что все процессы были завершены и потом попробуйте снова.
Если это не поможет, то возможно процесс git был ранее завершен
с ошибкой в этом репозитории:
удалите файл вручную для продолжени
```

message when I do a rebase, and I am quite sure that there aren't any other Git processes. At least a do not see any of them when I check them just after failing rebase command. Of course, every time I've immediately checked and saw that `/home/mingun/project/.git/index.lock` file did not exist.

Very often, I constantly get this error each time when I try to make a rebase, after few rebased commits the process failed with that error. To make matters worse, in most cases it is not possible to continue rebase:

```
git status
```

Output:

```
интерактивное перемещение в процессе; над e55e03330e3
Last commands done (21 commands done):
   pick 1a39bd4740d <skipped>
   pick f1906baf94b <skipped>
  (смотрите дополнительно в файле .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (13 remaining commands):
   pick 98db21878ed <skipped>
   pick 30488ef5a5a <skipped>
  (используйте «git rebase --edit-todo», чтобы просмотреть или изменить их)
Вы сейчас перемещаете ветку «master» над «e55e03330e3».
  (все конфликты разрешены: запустите «git rebase --continue»)

Изменения, которые будут включены в коммит:
    новый файл:    <skipped>
    изменено:      <skipped>
```

```
git rebase --continue
```

Output:

```
fatal: не удалось прочитать файл журнала «.git/rebase-merge/message»: Нет такого файла или каталога
error: не удалось закоммитить проиндексированные изменения.
```

Sometimes, if I wait several seconds between attempts, `git rebase` (`git svn rebase` actually) command finishes with success. But often you have to wait and try 10 times or more. The longer rebase todo, the higher chance that it finishes with that error.

When I tried to reproduce this bug with an English messages to post results in the bugtracker I was surprised to discover, that using `LANG=C` always fixes the problem! I think it's very suspicious to be an accident.

Another reason why I think this is a Git bug is that these errors have only begun to occur recently (probably a year ago), although my Git work pattern has not changed for a while.

So, if you encounter the same problem as me, try to prepend `LANG=C` to your commands:

```
LANG=C git svn rebase
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) for Windows:

Run these two commands

1. cd .git
2. rm index.lock

Comment: Given that the problem in the question was that he was not able to delete the file, why do you think trying to delete the file should be the solution?