# Error in deleting/addind file from appharbor using git "Unable to create 'f:/git/xyz/WorkerProcess/.git/index.lock': File exists"

Tags: git, appharbor

I want delete bin[or trying to run $git add .] from local git hub folder as well as on hosted app-harbor folder but i am unable to delete folder and getting following error

```
 $ git rm -r bin [ $ git rm -f bin]
 fatal: Unable to create 'f:/git/xyz/WorkerProcess/.git/index.lock': File
 exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
$ git clean -f  .git/index.lock
Removing .git/index.lock
comp1@SHAILESH01 /f/git/xyz/WorkerProcess (master)
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in f:/git/xyz/WorkerProcess/.git/
comp1@SHAILESH01 /f/git/xyz/WorkerProcess (master)
$ git add .
comp1@SHAILESH01 /f/git/xyz/WorkerProcess (master)
$ git rm  bin
fatal: not removing 'bin' recursively without -r
comp1@SHAILESH01 /f/git/xyz/WorkerProcess (master)
$ git rm -r -f bin
```