# fatal: Unable to create '/.git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

When I try to rename any image name in my `Xcode Project` it gives following error.

> ```
> fatal: Unable to create '/.git/index.lock': File exists. 
>
> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
> git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
> process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
> ```

Don't know what is going wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: this may halp's u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282632/git-index-lock-file-exists-when-i-try-to-commit-but-cannot-delete-the-file

Comment: I tried everything,but same result.

Comment: Check to see where you are issuing the command at. It should be issued at the root where you issued "git init"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - fatal: Unable to create '/path/my\_project/.git/index.lock': File exists.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

In your repository directory.

Comment: @DesertRose try `rm .git/index.lock`

Comment: @Deepesh Gairola Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had my local repo inside a Wordpress plugin folder hosted by Mamp on osx. The permissions for the local server was set to "www" in the Mamp permission settings. I changed the permissions back to me, and the "/index.lock“ needs to be removed manually."-problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

For me, $rm index.lock while in my git repository also solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project folder, go to git folder and remove `index.lock` file.