# Issue with Git Add

Tags: git, cloud9-ide

I recently started using Cloud9 IDE. I am using Git as version control and it was working fine, until recently I tried this command:

```
git add .
```

And it failed with this following error:

```
ubuntu:~/workspace (master) $ git add .
fatal: Unable to create '/home/ubuntu/workspace/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
ubuntu:~/workspace (master) $
```

I do have `sudo` permissions and using `sudo` with the above command gives me other errors. The index doesn't get updated. It still shows me like modified, but not added.

The crazy part is, that file `.git/index.lock` doesn't exist and also when I tried to find if there are any `git` processes running in the background, using `top` or `ps grep`, I couldn't find any.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in Cloud9 Environment. I am one of the collaborators with RW permission, but I don't have restart rights. I tried the following but they do not work:

```
sudo reboot
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Kindly let me know how to proceed. I need to deploy the code soon. By the way, this is my first post, as well as I have also seen similar posts here:

- [Stuck on Git on Windows: Can't checkout, can't stash, can't commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919650/stuck-on-git-on-windows-cant-checkout-cant-stash-cant-commit)
- [fatal: Unable to create '/.git/index.lock': File exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602544/fatal-unable-to-create-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Comment: Can you manually go to the directory and check the file? And delete using `sudo rm -f index.lock`? It is generally hidden.

Comment: @PraveenKumar No. That file doesn't exist in the location at all.

Comment: Can you try using filters like `ls -la` or something similar?

Comment: Possibly a permissions error. Try running sudo chown -R <user> .

Comment: @TomRees I have `sudo` permissions.

Comment: Agreed. But you say that running as sudo gives other errors. I'm suggesting running add as the non super-user, but eliminating the possibility of permissions errors by changing the owner of all the files/directories first.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -al /home/ubuntu/workspace/.git/`?

Comment: @TomRees Ah yeah... I was answering and you said it in the comments. :P

Comment: @LeeNetherton Lemme try...

Comment: @LeeNetherton That gives me a super long list. Shouldn't I add a `*` at the end?

Comment: @GitUser It shouldn't be that long, maybe 20 lines? Just put the output in your original post

Comment: @LeeNetherton I got it working by running `chmod`.

Comment: @TomRees You were right. Do you know what caused it, as it was working fine till yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R .git
sudo chown -R ubuntu:root .git
```

This is true if the file doesn't exist. Looks like a permission issue to me.

Comment: @GitUser As people mentioned in the comments, it was because of permissions issue. Generally Cloud9 IDEs are stable, and I am not sure how you went into such an issue.

Comment: Since you have already changed the permission, I am not sure what was there previously. So, couldn't tell exactly why didn't it work before. So... :(

Comment: Do you know what caused it, as it was working fine till yesterday.

Comment: As I said you, you have already reset the permission on the file, so there's no way possible to get the history of who originally owned the file at first. Not really sure what caused the permissions issue at first place. That too on a hidden directory like `.git`.

Comment: @GitUser you must have run a git command as root at some point, which affected the permissions in the .git directory.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am stuck with another CSS question. How do I ask you?

Comment: @GitUser You can always use the [Ask a Question](/questions/ask) and ping the link here, if you feel it is relevant to me or this question. Happy to answer for you... `:)`