# Git error when trying to push: Discard Changes - Cannot unlock

Tags: git, github

Im currently using git repository. Unable to push my files to the remote repository.

It says "Discard Changes  - Cannot unlock" for C:/somelocation/.git/index.

No other details to figure out the problem.

[image]

Even tried to reset.

> git reset

But gives the below error.

An internal error occurred during: "Resetting to refs/heads/develop".
Exception caught during execution of reset command. {0}

Answer (score 5):

Try deleting `C:/somelocation/.git/index.lock`. **[More on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282632/git-index-lock-file-exists-when-i-try-to-commit-but-cannot-delete-the-file)**

You may then need to do a reset:

```
git reset
```

Comment: An internal error occurred during: "Resetting to refs/heads/develop". Exception caught during execution of reset command. {0}