# GIT | What causes git error: 'fatal: Unable to create '/index.lock': Permission denied' error?

Tags: git, magento, error-handling, permissions, file-permissions

I have a question that I can't answer myself, even with the Uncle Google's help.

While I try to use '**git checkout**' command in one of my projects I got error like this:

```
'fatal: Unable to create *'some/directory/path/index.lock'*: Permission denied'
```

I am aware that this issue is related to permissions inside .git directory. What I would like to know is what actions are leading to such situation and how to prevent them in the future.

TL;DR **What causes  'fatal: Unable to create '/index.lock': Permission denied' error?**

Answer (score 2):

I can't add comments yet, but The who's comment on this [git index.lock File exists when I try to commit, but cannot delete the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282632/git-index-lock-file-exists-when-i-try-to-commit-but-cannot-delete-the-file) question might be an answer.

I think he's right, that another process interferes with the git repo.