# How to end 'another git process' running in same repository?

Tags: github

After my first attempt at committing a couple of large folders (angular and django), git responded with:

```
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Previous posts recommend:

removing the index.lock in the .git folder.

I've done this, but the second that i resubmit "git add . " as part of my git push origin master routine, the index.lock file reappears in .git

Is there another solution? And what has happened to warrant this?

I've tried all the suggestions in the commented link

I'm working with this:

```
 git version 2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)
```

Comment: Did you try all the solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282632/6309? Are you on Windows? What is your git version?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, index.lock wouldn't delete.  Instead, I found that one of my django folders lacked a .gitignore, so I created one and included the following files:

```
include
lib
include
bin
.vscode
```

You might want to include more or less, depending.. Apparently, I was attempting to push a file that disagreed with git.