# How to resolve Git permission denied /.git/index.lock

Tags: git, macos, github-for-mac

I'm logged in as an admin user but cannot checkin files into a git repository. I keep getting:

```
fatal: Unable to create '.../.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

I did try `ls -la .git/index.lock` but get a not exist error.

I haven't found anything to fix this. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove .git/index.lock': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127255/remove-git-index-lock-permission-denied)

Comment: No. I'm in the repository folder and can see the hidden .git folder. When I run "ls -la /.git/index.lock", I get "No such file or directory." I just deleted the local repository and downloaded it again. This time I'm able to checkin. Maybe all of the previous commends + deleting fixed it. Who knows.

Comment: I hope you did `ls -la .git/index.lock` and not `ls -la /.git/index.lock`. Else it might have existed, but you might have happened to look at the wrong place.

Comment: Neither one worked.

Comment: Your operating system is denying Git permission to *create* the file `index.lock` in that directory (or folder). Since you are on MacOS, it's not some crazy Windows thing. Check the ownership and permissions of the `.git` directory (`ls -ld .git`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running several command lines with no luck, I deleted the index.lock file. Then ran more commands with no luck. Then I deleted the local repository and downloaded again. This time everything is working and I can check in files.

Answer (score 2):

The quick way is to delete the file.

```sh
cd <repo-dir>
rm -rf .git/index.lock
```

You may want to setup the permissions properly.

```sh
sudo chown -R <owner>:<group> .git # set group
sudo chmod -R 775 .git # access rights
```

From internet search

> When you perform a Git command that edits the index, Git creates a new index.lock file, writes the changes, and then renames the file. The index.lock file indicates to other Git processes that the repository is locked for editing.

Comment: After you delete the file, how do you get it back? I tried a pull and it did not reappear.

Comment: You dont need it. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting index.lock file in your .git directory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the permissions; however, every time the action was executed, the permissions were changed. The only way I found was to delete the index file.

```
rm -rf .git/index
```