# What does the .git/index.lock file actually do?

Tags: git, locking

I have had the issue currently where I needed to remove my `.git/index.lock` file. Without too much hesitation I am guessing that this file somehow locks processes that can access the git repo. However I can't seem to find a good description/documentation for what this file actually does and why you get the problem described for instance [in this question(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists).

**What does the `index.lock` actually do, and what causes the problem that people are having related to this file?**

It would be very nice to know so I can prevent this issue in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found this from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/api-lockfile.html. This tells you what `.git/index.lock` does.

> - Mutual exclusion.  When we write out a new index file, first
>     we create a new file `$GIT_DIR/index.lock`, write the new
>     contents into it, and rename it to the final destination
>     `$GIT_DIR/index`.  We try to create the `$GIT_DIR/index.lock`
>     file with O_EXCL so that we can notice and fail when somebody
>     else is already trying to update the index file.
> - Automatic cruft removal.  After we create the "lock" file, we
>     may decide to `die()`, and we would want to make sure that we
>     remove the file that has not been committed to its final
>     destination.  This is done by remembering the lockfiles we
>     created in a linked list and cleaning them up from an
>     `atexit(3)` handler.  Outstanding lockfiles are also removed
>     when the program dies on a signal.

I guess the reason of the problem you said is malfunction of the Automatic cruft removal on some OS. I have used Git on Linux since a few years ago, but not experienced such kind of problem yet.