# Why " '/path/to/repo/.git/index.lock': File exists" issue happened?

Tags: git

I don't know what happened to my system because from last week it is giving this error continuously 2-3 times on daily basis.

```
fatal: Unable to create '/path/to/repo/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

I have remove this is file every time and currently it became a big pain for me.

Can anybody explain why it is happening continuously or what are its expected causes/reasons or anything that can help me to avoid this thing, at least on daily bases it should not happen.

Comment: Did you run as Sudo?  May not have permissions to manage the file.

Comment: `sudo` where.??

I am the admin of my system and I don't why all of a sudden it just start happening from last few days :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - fatal: Unable to create '/path/my\_project/.git/index.lock': File exists.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Comment: I would just check the permissions anyway.  If there's something weird in the in file ownership try modifying it.  You've already found the solution (deletion) in the linked comment so I think your issue is slightly different.

Comment: @devnull - I know the work around of the issue but I wanted to know the reason like why this is happening. So the purpose of this question is different. I couldn't find the reason anywhere thats why I posted this question.

Comment: What is your platform ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen several times in the office.

Basically, what happened here was - a git console command was inputted, while at the same time a visual client was running some command on its own. In the end both fail to delete the index.lock file, without any other side effects of problems caused.

I usually just deleted my original index file and replaced it with the index.lock version just in case.

Comment: Thanks Jedy but I am not using any visual client, never. Just terminal :)