# Git index.lock file exists

Tags: python, multithreading, git, github

Sorry about duplicate title but I am unable to follow the answers. 
Here's my situation: 
I have a repository Abcd.
I have folder X and folder Y; I have cloned Abcd in both folders.
Now I have a python code running, in multi-threading and it does the following:

> subprocess.check_call(['git', 'fetch', gitSettings.server_name_gear]) 
>   subprocess.check_call(['git', 'remote', 'prune', 'origin'])
>   subprocess.check_call(['git', 'checkout', '-f', branch])

This code executes on Abcd in folder X

and I get the error as follows:

> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
>   git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
>   process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
>   using through thread 1 and on Abcd in folder Y using thread 2.

sorry for naming convention as well, I am just trying to simplify.

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like you can run multiple git indexes at once

Comment: Try rm -f ./.git/index.lock per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists

Comment: @DavidN I tried doing that, then also I ended up with same error.

Comment: @nbryans I did not understand what you mean.