# AWS codecommit can't connect to 2nd repo with HTTPS protocol using Git Credentials

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree, aws-codecommit

I was going to connect to a second repository on AWS Codecommit(I already connect another one), but I got an error, though I am able to connect to this second repository,DL, though MINGW32.

No be noted, Repositoy was already existing locally so, I connected to the one remote one via [SSH](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html) first time, and pushed all the code, then also executed git commands(mostly push) using HTTPS with [git credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html).

So far I am the only one using the repo.

I used root account(though is not advisable for security reason) as it is simply a test-project repo and still getting familiar with AWS, for the first repository. Then as it simple to set up for use SourceTree(and I everything was ok following these [instructions](https://geekprotem.com/2015/07/10/aws-codecommit-with-sourcetree/)  and also Pycharm I set access to this repo1 via HTTPS.

I was, and still able to execute *git command to the remote branches. No problem at all.

Then after few months I decide to have another repo, in the same account(a root one).
This time I decide to go though directly to use HTTPS via git credentials. Followed same procedure, but this time I messed up, not I have this

[image]

executing

```
git remote -v
```

So I have unwanted "origin" repo, that is not visible on AWS, and was made because I followed normal instructions.
Except that, it seems as it should be.
Unfortunately since I tried to add the bees.txt, SourceTree is hunging without asking me to add or commit the file, and adding it manually I get this:

```
fatal: Unable to create 
'C:/Users/Carmine/.virtualenvs/DL/Scripts/src/.git/index.lock': File 
exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

(it seems is trying to alterate, so indeed adding a new file, the index, but the same is busy with something so, cannot proceed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update-Solution

I get rid of git error executing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists/22304383)

Then through command line I added the test file and committed test file. Then as the repository was an already filled in with files, I added them.

Later I pushed everything to remote master branch. After that I manually deleted from SourceTree the unwanted(but not sincronized) remote/ mirror repository. Now everything seems works, so I was able to connect via HTTPS to AWS