# index.lock does not exist when trying to remove it

Tags: git

I'm trying to add a few files to git.

Issue is I'm having this error `fatal: Impossible de créer '/home/andy_k/Documents/dev/forsure/.git/index.lock' : Permission not granted`

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860765/2572645), doing a `rm -f ./.git/index.lock` should be enough.

But there is no such file.

Any ideas on what should be my next step?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you don’t have permission to create files within `.git`. Do you own it and have write permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the owner of the .git folder in the directory using (considering you have linux/mac OS)

```
ls -l -a
```

if the owner is other then current user, then

```
sudo chown -R <current_username> .git
```

Then again try committing files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a permission problem.
 Are you the owner of the folder .get? 
(If not use `chown` command to change it)
The Permission should be "rwxrwxr-x" (775) (you can change it with the command `chmod`)