# GitHub Desktop : fatal error "unable to create /project/.git/index.lock : no such file or directory"

Tags: git

**This should not be the same as the error "index.lock: file exists" as it DOES NOT EXIST for mine. I CANNOT DELETE or REMOVE the index.lock file if it DOES NOT EXIST hence the question.**

**This will be the error that i receive**
[image: rm .git/index.lock command error]

---

Error when commiting

[image: error when commiting]

Details :

(Before this, everything was working fine)

I opened GitHub desktop 
and I wanted to continue my project 
but when I wanted to commit, 
it gave me the above error.

So i tried cloning another repo 
and to my surprise i got this error message (below)

Error when cloning another repo

[image: error when cloning another repo]

I used the git clone command to clone the new repo and it is successful however
when i tried adding a new file and commiting it to that repo
the same

> index.lock: no such file or directory

error pops out.

Here are my logs.

```html
2019-02-18T07:03:51.676Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 2 repositories from store
2019-02-18T07:03:51.692Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account: RichelleT (Richelle Tan)
2019-02-18T07:03:53.758Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.6.2 (Windows 10.0.17134)
2019-02-18T07:03:53.758Z - info: [ui] execPath: 'C:\Users\J0hnz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\GitHubDesktop.exe'
2019-02-18T07:03:54.825Z - info: [ui] Executing installGlobalLFSFilter: git lfs install --skip-repo (took 1.511s)
2019-02-18T07:04:00.691Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.withAuthenticatingUser] account found for repository: Python - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:04:03.773Z - info: [ui] Executing pull: git -c credential.helper= pull --no-rebase --progress origin (took 2.899s)
2019-02-18T07:04:03.776Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= pull --no-rebase --progress origin` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.        
remote: Counting objects:  20% (1/5)           
remote: Counting objects:  40% (2/5)           
remote: Counting objects:  60% (3/5)           
remote: Counting objects:  80% (4/5)           
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5)           
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.        
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (1/3)           
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (2/3)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.        
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
error: unable to create temporary file: No such file or directory
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed

2019-02-18T07:04:12.376Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 2.667s)
2019-02-18T07:04:12.376Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.        
remote: Counting objects:  20% (1/5)           
remote: Counting objects:  40% (2/5)           
remote: Counting objects:  60% (3/5)           
remote: Counting objects:  80% (4/5)           
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5)           
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.        
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (1/3)           
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (2/3)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.        
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': No such file or directory
From https://github.com/RichelleT/CS50
 ! a520519..58105b8  master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)

2019-02-18T07:04:19.558Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.withAuthenticatingUser] account found for repository: Python - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:04:21.308Z - info: [ui] Executing pull: git -c credential.helper= pull --no-rebase --progress origin (took 1.567s)
2019-02-18T07:04:21.308Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= pull --no-rebase --progress origin` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': No such file or directory
From https://github.com/RichelleT/CS50
 ! a520519..58105b8  master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)

2019-02-18T07:04:55.903Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:04:56.107Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:05:02.824Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:05:03.016Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:05:34.281Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:05:34.454Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:12:58.741Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:12:58.991Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:13:23.369Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:13:23.593Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Java/.git: No such file or directory
Cloning into 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java'...

2019-02-18T07:13:38.321Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.522s)
2019-02-18T07:13:58.217Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:13:58.356Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Java/.git: No such file or directory
Cloning into 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java'...

2019-02-18T07:14:39.065Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:14:39.287Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:15:59.647Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:15:59.785Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:16:07.750Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 1 repositories from store
2019-02-18T07:16:07.753Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account: RichelleT (Richelle Tan)
2019-02-18T07:16:08.207Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.6.2 (Windows 10.0.17134)
2019-02-18T07:16:08.208Z - info: [ui] execPath: 'C:\Users\J0hnz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\GitHubDesktop.exe'
2019-02-18T07:16:16.179Z - info: [main] opening in browser: https://github.com/RichelleT/DjangoProjects
2019-02-18T07:16:27.858Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:16:28.077Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:16:33.481Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.846s)
2019-02-18T07:16:50.832Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:16:51.058Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:18:07.704Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.946s)
2019-02-18T07:18:11.594Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.withAuthenticatingUser] account found for repository: DjangoProjects - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:18:13.180Z - info: [ui] Executing pull: git -c credential.helper= pull --no-rebase --progress origin (took 1.452s)
2019-02-18T07:18:13.180Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= pull --no-rebase --progress origin` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'ORIG_HEAD': could not open '.git/ORIG_HEAD' for writing: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:18:49.074Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:18:49.283Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:20:44.549Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 1 repositories from store
2019-02-18T07:20:44.551Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account: RichelleT (Richelle Tan)
2019-02-18T07:20:45.153Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.6.2 (Windows 10.0.17134)
2019-02-18T07:20:45.154Z - info: [ui] execPath: 'C:\Users\J0hnz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\GitHubDesktop.exe'
2019-02-18T07:20:51.474Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:20:51.694Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:21:38.822Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:21:39.093Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:23:30.484Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:23:30.708Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:25:21.963Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 1 repositories from store
2019-02-18T07:25:21.965Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account: RichelleT (Richelle Tan)
2019-02-18T07:25:22.512Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.6.2 (Windows 10.0.17134)
2019-02-18T07:25:22.513Z - info: [ui] execPath: 'C:\Users\J0hnz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\GitHubDesktop.exe'
2019-02-18T07:25:48.140Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.638s)
2019-02-18T07:25:56.036Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:25:56.265Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:30:05.055Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:30:05.273Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git: No such file or directory
Cloning into 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python'...

2019-02-18T07:31:22.827Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 3
2019-02-18T07:31:22.827Z - info: [main] Processing protocol url
2019-02-18T07:31:26.973Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:31:27.200Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git: No such file or directory
Cloning into 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python'...

2019-02-18T07:31:27.201Z - warn: [ui] Open Repository from URL failed, did not find or clone repository: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python - payload: {"branch":null,"filepath":null,"name":"open-repository-from-url","pr":null,"url":"https://github.com/RichelleT/Python"}
2019-02-18T07:31:48.419Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 3
2019-02-18T07:31:48.419Z - info: [main] Processing protocol url
2019-02-18T07:31:49.835Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:31:50.103Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:31:50.103Z - warn: [ui] Open Repository from URL failed, did not find or clone repository: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python - payload: {"branch":null,"filepath":null,"name":"open-repository-from-url","pr":null,"url":"https://github.com/RichelleT/Python"}
2019-02-18T07:32:33.346Z - error: [ui] `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

(The error was parsed as 27: This is not a git repository.)
2019-02-18T07:32:52.430Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] adding repository at C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python to store
2019-02-18T07:32:54.157Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.590s)
2019-02-18T07:32:54.641Z - info: [ui] Executing isUsingLFS: git lfs track (took 2.032s)
2019-02-18T07:32:54.645Z - error: [ui] createRepository: unable to write .gitattributes at C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python\.gitattributes'
2019-02-18T07:32:55.099Z - error: [ui] `git reset -- .` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:32:55.660Z - error: [ui] createRepository: initial commit failed at C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python
GitError: fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

    at Object.t.git (C:\Users\J0hnz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.1\webpack:\app\src\lib\git\core.ts:174:2)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
2019-02-18T07:33:08.587Z - error: [ui] `git update-index --add --remove --replace -z --stdin` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Harvard's CS50/hello.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: unable to create temporary file: No such file or directory
error: Harvard's CS50/hello.py: failed to insert into database
fatal: Unable to process path Harvard's CS50/hello.py

2019-02-18T07:33:25.666Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.574s)
2019-02-18T07:33:31.216Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:33:31.422Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:35:00.278Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 1 repositories from store
2019-02-18T07:35:00.280Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account: RichelleT (Richelle Tan)
2019-02-18T07:35:00.747Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.6.2 (Windows 10.0.17134)
2019-02-18T07:35:00.747Z - info: [ui] execPath: 'C:\Users\J0hnz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\GitHubDesktop.exe'
2019-02-18T07:35:06.260Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 2.180s)
2019-02-18T07:35:35.135Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:35:35.339Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:56:09.097Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 3
2019-02-18T07:56:09.100Z - info: [main] Processing protocol url
2019-02-18T07:56:12.588Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 1 repositories from store
2019-02-18T07:56:12.588Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account: RichelleT (Richelle Tan)
2019-02-18T07:56:14.694Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.6.2 (Windows 10.0.17134)
2019-02-18T07:56:14.694Z - info: [ui] execPath: 'C:\Users\J0hnz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\GitHubDesktop.exe'
2019-02-18T07:56:17.126Z - info: [ui] Executing getStatus: git --no-optional-locks status --untracked-files=all --branch --porcelain=2 -z (took 3.921s)
2019-02-18T07:56:17.128Z - info: [ui] Executing getStatus: git --no-optional-locks status --untracked-files=all --branch --porcelain=2 -z (took 4.072s)
2019-02-18T07:56:17.381Z - info: [ui] Executing getRemotes: git remote -v (took 1.282s)
2019-02-18T07:56:17.879Z - info: [ui] Executing installGlobalLFSFilter: git lfs install --skip-repo (took 4.659s)
2019-02-18T07:56:19.647Z - info: [ui] Executing getBranches: git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(refname:short)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(objectname:short)%00%(author)%00%(committer)%00%(parent)%00%(symref)%00%(subject)%00%(body)%00%(trailers:unfold,only)%00%1F refs/heads refs/remotes (took 1.199s)
2019-02-18T07:56:19.981Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:56:20.336Z - info: [ui] Executing getRecentBranches: git log -g --no-abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline HEAD -n 2500 -- (took 1.534s)
2019-02-18T07:56:20.605Z - info: [ui] Executing getRecentBranches: git log -g --no-abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline HEAD -n 2500 -- (took 2.028s)
2019-02-18T07:56:20.954Z - info: [ui] Executing getRecentBranches: git log -g --no-abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline HEAD -n 2500 -- (took 1.814s)
2019-02-18T07:56:21.552Z - info: [ui] Executing getCommits: git log origin/master..master --date=raw --max-count=100 --pretty=%H%x1F%h%x1F%s%x1F%b%x1F%an <%ae> %ad%x1F%cn <%ce> %cd%x1F%P%x1F%(trailers:unfold,only) -z --no-show-signature --no-color -- (took 1.209s)
2019-02-18T07:56:21.743Z - info: [ui] Executing getAuthorIdentity: git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT (took 1.231s)
2019-02-18T07:56:21.744Z - info: [ui] Executing getRemotes: git remote -v (took 1.343s)
2019-02-18T07:56:21.983Z - info: [ui] Executing getCommits: git log origin/master..master --date=raw --max-count=100 --pretty=%H%x1F%h%x1F%s%x1F%b%x1F%an <%ae> %ad%x1F%cn <%ce> %cd%x1F%P%x1F%(trailers:unfold,only) -z --no-show-signature --no-color -- (took 1.027s)
2019-02-18T07:56:22.626Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T07:56:22.629Z - warn: [ui] Open Repository from URL failed, did not find or clone repository: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python - payload: {"branch":null,"filepath":null,"name":"open-repository-from-url","pr":null,"url":"https://github.com/RichelleT/Python"}
2019-02-18T07:58:29.165Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T07:58:29.421Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Python.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:18:39.560Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 1
2019-02-18T08:19:05.609Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] adding repository at C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Python to store
2019-02-18T08:19:07.571Z - info: [ui] Executing isUsingLFS: git lfs track (took 1.688s)
2019-02-18T08:19:09.038Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 3.077s)
2019-02-18T08:23:00.968Z - error: [ui] `git reset -- .` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:24:13.404Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:28:16.466Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.withAuthenticatingUser] account found for repository: Python - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T08:28:16.802Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:28:18.127Z - info: [ui] Background fetch for 2 repositories took 4.058sec
2019-02-18T08:29:00.987Z - error: [ui] `git reset -- .` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:29:19.634Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:34:26.706Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:37:42.920Z - error: [ui] `git reset -- .` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:39:33.789Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:40:20.898Z - error: [ui] `git reset -- .` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/J0hnz/Desktop/Python/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:43:17.059Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.withAuthenticatingUser] account found for repository: Python - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T08:43:17.511Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:43:19.092Z - info: [ui] Background fetch for 2 repositories took 5.017sec
2019-02-18T08:44:39.961Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:48:00.532Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.getAccountForRemoteURL] account found for remote: https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T08:48:00.959Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://github.com/RichelleT/Java.git C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\J0hnz\Desktop\Java': No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:58:16.892Z - info: [ui] [AppStore.withAuthenticatingUser] account found for repository: Python - RichelleT (has token)
2019-02-18T08:58:17.178Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin` exited with an unexpected code: 255.
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: No such file or directory

2019-02-18T08:58:18.153Z - info: [ui] Background fetch for 2 repositories took 3.764sec
```

Comment: In my friend's case Windoze Defender was blocking the file for whatever reason.

Answer (score -1):

A problem similar to already resolved, with this comande `rm -f ./.git/index.lock` here is the link [fatal: Unable to create '/path/my_proj/.git/index.lock': File exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Comment: unfortunately i have seen that thread and tried the above command as well. the error still persists

Comment: I have updated the post with the error message that  i get from running the particular command

Comment: This question is different from that ``File exists``. May I ask the site administrators to re-open this question, please?

I got a problem - I changed a file, and ran git status, but the changed file is not displayed! I wanted to add the changed file, but it gave me an error message, saying ``fatal: Unable to create '.git/index.lock': No such file or directory'``. 
Solution: Go to 'Windows security'. Turn off 'Secured folder access'.

Comment: Then run git add again. If ``fatal: Unable to create '.git/index.lock': File exists``, then go to .git/, rm -r index.lock. Then you can run git add successfully.