# when i try to do a git commit to my file i got this error on the terminal and I don't know how to solve this problem

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, github, terminal, web-frontend

PS D:\Bootstrap4\conFusion> git add
fatal: Unable to create 'D:/Bootstrap4/conFusion/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.

Comment: Make sure there are no git processes in memory then try again. If the error persists, then do as the error says and delete index.lock.

Comment: how we can know if there is git processes in memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - fatal: Unable to create '/path/my\_project/.git/index.lock': File exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Comment: not really it doen't help me to fix my problem and when I tried to search for this one D:/Bootstrap4/conFusion/.git/index.lock to delete it manually i didn't find it

Comment: can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your folder of the current repository
2. Then check .git folder which is hidden folder
3. Delete index.lock file