# Error in local git repository for app service

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to update my react app service. No matter the method the deployment center says it fails and the logs return the next message:

> fatal: Unable to create '/home/site/repository/.git/index.lock': File exists.\n\nAnother git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.\nan editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes\nare terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process\nmay have crashed in this repository earlier:\nremove the file manually to continue.\n\n/usr/bin/git checkout master --force

How can I "restart" or fix the local git repository of my app service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - fatal: Unable to create '/path/my\_project/.git/index.lock': File exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that you execute two `git` commands simultaneously one from the command prompt and one from an IDE.

To fix this issue you can **remove** the `Index.lock` file follow below code

For **linux/unix/gitbash** use the below command:

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

For **Windows** use the below Command:

```
del .git\index.lock
```

or delete the **last commit** changes.

```
rm .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

If you run by using `IDE` please ***close*** the `IDE` and run the `git` command in Cmdr.

Use below command to check the reason why the working tree is locked or not.
**--reason < string>**

With **lock** or with **add --lock**, an explanation why the working tree is locked.

Refer [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt---reasonltstringgt)

Comment: Yes this seems to be the answer but I can't find a way to clean the file and run the command from the app service local repository :/