# git track a folder which used to have it's own git inside it

Tags: git

I have a project where I've copied in git projects from a couple of other projects. I don't need to complicate things with submodules, I just need to track my whole project. So I removed the .git folders from the things I've copied in.

For demonstration:

```
mainprojectfolder
   subfolder
   subfolder2
       .git
```

is now

```
mainprojectfolder
   subfolder
   subfolder2
```

but for some reason I still can't add my `subfolder2` to my work tree at all. It's definitely there, I've even made changes to files inside it since removing git from it, but it just won't be added and it doesn't show up when I try `git status -u --ignored` either.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using `git add -f` to add a dummy file in `subfolder2` or directly under `mainprojectfolder` to see if the new file gets picked up by a `git status`. There could also be the possibility that your index is somehow corrupted, so you could try remove `.git/index` in `mainprojectfolder` and Git will rebuild it.

Some tips raised in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619883/cannot-see-new-files-added-to-my-git-working-directory) might also help.